# Software for back ups that fulfills the listed requirements

Tags: windows, backup, debian

I am searching for a back up software that fulfills the following requirements:

- Compatible for Debian and Windows (Portable version available on Windows)
- Automated back up as soon as the destination device (e.g a hard drive) is plugged
- Check if the files in the source directory are in the destination device. Ignoring if there are more files in the destiny directory i.e: Not a complete synchronization of both folders 1:1

  - Allow incremental back ups

Does anyone know a software that allow to do this?

Comment: “Destiny medium”? A fortune-teller?

Comment: xD Sometimes I can be really esoteric